# Inner Gatling expressions

Tags: scala, gatling

I have a CSV file with a single column, which contains a JSON array. Each JSON object in the array has a field `version` which is a time in miliseconds.

```
myCol
[{"id": 1, version: 234343535}, {"id": 2, version: 23455454}, ...]
```

Is it possible to regenerate the version during slimulation running? Currently, Im' injecting the array as a `StringBody("${myCol}")`

Does Gatling EL allows to modify i.e. the `version` during runtime? Or do I have to use `session` and run through the string searching for `version` field?

Answer (score 0):

Gatling Expression Language is read only, so indeed, you have to code your own transformation function with the [Session API](https://gatling.io/docs/current/session/session_api/).

Depending on how much constant things there are in your records, you might want to drop using a feeder and directly generate the full JSON payload on the fly.